# How do I send a function parameter to AsyncStorage?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to send the parameter to the function `submitLanguageSelection`, which is `userSelectedLanguage`, to a custom hook I've written which (hopefully) saves that parameter to `AsyncStorage`. The user selects a language, either English or Arabic, from one of the two buttons.

This is my first time ever doing this. I've gotten very stuck.

I would like the `submitLanguageSelection` function to call the `saveData` function which is made available through the `useLocalStorage` hook. I would like the user's choice of language to be persisted in `AsyncStorage` so I can then later render the `ChooseYourLanguageScreen` according to whether the user has selected a language or not.

Here is the cutom hook, `useLocalStorage`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Alert } from 'react-native';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

const STORAGE_KEY = '@has_stored_value';

export default () => {
  const [storedValue, setStoredValue] = React.useState('');
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = React.useState('');

  const saveData = async () => {
    try {
      const localValue = await AsyncStorage.setItem(STORAGE_KEY, storedValue);
      if (localValue !== null) {
        setStoredValue(storedValue);
        Alert.alert('Data successfully saved');
      }
      console.log('stored val', storedValue);
    } catch (e) {
      setErrorMessage('Something went wrong');
    }
  };
  return [saveData, errorMessage];
};
```

Here is the `ChooseYourLanguageScreen`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Button } from 'react-native';
import useLocalStorage from '../hooks/useLocalStorage';

const ChooseYourLanguageScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [saveData, errorMessage] = useLocalStorage();

  const submitLanguageSelection = (userSelectedLanguage) => {
    //TODO: save the data locally
    //TODO: navigate to welcome screen

    // at the moment, the language choice isn't making it to useLocalStorage

    if (userSelectedLanguage !== null) {
      console.log('user selected lang', userSelectedLanguage);
      saveData(userSelectedLanguage);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {errorMessage ? <Text>{errorMessage}</Text> : null}
      <Text style={styles.text}>This is the Choose Your Language Screen</Text>
      <View style={styles.buttons}>
        <View>
          <Button
            title={'English'}
            onPress={() => submitLanguageSelection('English')}
          />
        </View>
        <View>
          <Button
            title={'Arabic'}
            onPress={() => submitLanguageSelection('Arabic')}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  text: {
    alignSelf: 'center',
  },
  buttons: {
    backgroundColor: '#DDDDDD',
    padding: 10,
  },
});

export default ChooseYourLanguageScreen;
```

Comment: The `saveData()` function needs a parameter variable.

Comment: Thank you @Barmar! I had gotten to the point where I'd been looking at it for so long that my eyes could no longer see the code, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`saveData()` needs a parameter. You can provide a default value that uses `storedValue` that came from `React.useState()`, but when you call it with an explicit argument it will override that default.

```
export default () => {
  const [storedValue, setStoredValue] = React.useState('');
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = React.useState('');

  const saveData = async (dataToSave = storedValue) => {
    try {
      const localValue = await AsyncStorage.setItem(STORAGE_KEY, dataToSave);
      if (localValue !== null) {
        setStoredValue(dataToSave);
        Alert.alert('Data successfully saved');
      }
      console.log('stored val', dataToSave);
    } catch (e) {
      setErrorMessage('Something went wrong');
    }
  };
  return [saveData, errorMessage];
};
```